# Error in using finContours function and downloading ntdll files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, ntdll

I am a newbie in using VS2012 & openCV for the completion of my FYP where I have to detect human bodies(Object detection) using Contours. I have installed successfully both (VS2012 & openCV) & had been doing some basic image processing without any unknown problem other than logical or syntactical until I came across using the findContours function where I am detained right now. My problem is:

When I do not use the Contour related stuff i.e. findContours , drawContours, by commenting it, every thing is fine and I can use trackbar to dilate/erode the image but as soon as I use Contour related stuff and press ‘F5’, the image showing contours around the detected objects is shown along with breakpoint saying Program.exe has triggered a break point and hence I can’t use it further.

For your convenience, following are the  listings in stack trace:

Note 1:
I have followed the instructions given by [pbrandoli](/questions/tagged/pbrandoli)  , but after loading the Un-Highlighted “ntdll.dll & msvcr” via Microsoft symbol servers gets highlighted  & on restarting (Cntrl+Shift+F5) or debugging(F5) it again gets Un-highlighted indicating that it is missing.

Note 2: I have concised the list for convenience.

```
ntdll.dll!77ca5204()    Unknown
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
    ntdll.dll!77c6fbae()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!77c02b04()    Unknown
    KernelBase.dll!75ff7e27()   Unknown
>   msvcr110d.dll!_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(const void * pUserData) Line 2036  C++
    msvcr110d.dll!_free_dbg_nolock(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse) Line 1322   C++
    msvcr110d.dll!_free_dbg(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse) Line 1265  C++
    msvcr110d.dll!operator delete(void * pUserData) Line 54 C++
    binaryFrame.exe!std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> >::deallocate(cv::Point_<int> * _Ptr, 
unsigned int __formal) Line 586 C++
    binaryFrame.exe!std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > 
>::deallocate(cv::Point_<int> * _Ptr, unsigned int _Count) Line 888 C++
    binaryFrame.exe!std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >::_Tidy() 
    binaryFrame.exe!showBinImage() Line 66  C++
    binaryFrame.exe!main(int __formal, char * * argv) Line 21   C++
    binaryFrame.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 536    C
    binaryFrame.exe!mainCRTStartup() Line 377   C
    kernel32.dll!763e1154() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!77c3b299()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!77c3b26c()    Unknown
```

following is the code that i am using for contour detection in image:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void showBinImage();

int val=2;


int main( int, char** argv )
{
    showBinImage();
    return 0;
}  


void showBinImage(){
Mat bin;
Mat im_gray;   


Mat im_rgb  = imread("nk5.jpg");

        //  Trackbar

namedWindow("ErodedImage",1);
createTrackbar("Erode", "ErodedImage", &val, 50);

cvtColor(im_rgb, im_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);
threshold(im_gray, bin, 128.0, 255.0, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
//imwrite("bnasir.jpg", img_bw);
namedWindow("Binary",1);
imshow("Binary", bin);

while (true)
{

Mat erodeElement = getStructuringElement( MORPH_CROSS,Size(val*3,val*3));   
Mat dilateElement = getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT,Size(val*8,val*8));
Mat eroded; // the destination image
erode(bin,eroded,erodeElement+50);
dilate(eroded,eroded,dilateElement);    
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;       
findContours(eroded, contours, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);  
// Draw black contours on a white image
Mat result(eroded.size(),CV_8U,cv::Scalar(255));
drawContours(result,contours,-1, cv::Scalar(0), 2); // with a thickness of 2
imshow("ErodedImage",(eroded));
waitKey(10);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched from VS2012 to VS2010 and now every thing works fine! I don't know what is the problem with VS2012 because VS2013 also provides results as VS2010 but to use VS2013, u need Windows 8 OS. Hence i came back to Older version since i am using Windows 7 OS!